# Specify column data type with a <th> attribute for DataTables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

We're using the DataTables jQuery plugin (http://www.datatables.net) to create sortable tables. This plugin auto-detects the data type of the data in each column.

When you want to specify the data type of a column yourself, you add the "aoColumns" attribute when you initialize the datatable:

```
$('#accountTable').dataTable({
    "bPaginate": false,
    "sScrollX": "100%",
    "bScrollCollapse": true,
    "aoColumns": [
        null,
        null,
        { "sType": "currency" },
        { "sType": "currency" }
    ]
});
```

Note, I downloaded the currency data type plugin for datatables.  This works great.

However, I'm concerned that if we ever make changes to the table column, we'll forget to go back into the JS and change how the datatables plugin is initialized on that table.

So... It would be ideal to specify the data types directly in the table as necessary:

```
<table class="dataTables display">
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>Category</th>
        <th>Product</th>
        <th sType="currency">Cost</th>
        <th sType="currency">Retail</th>
        ...
```

Is there any way to do this, either with default functionality of DataTables (which I can't find) or using a JS loop or something to loop through the  tags of the table and update the sType where "sType" attribute exists?

Comment: Use HTML custom data attributes – and just select their content when building your config data structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to all for your help! I had to make a couple tweaks to Russell Zahniser's comment for it to work for me:

1. Changed $('#accountTable > th') to $('#accountTable thead th')
2. Changed aoColumns.push(sType ? sType : null) to aoColumns.push(sType ? { "sType" : "currency" } : null)

End result:

```
var aoColumns = [];

$('#accountTable thead th').each(function() {
   var sType = $(this).getAttribute("data-sType");
   aoColumns.push(sType ? { "sType" : "currency" } : null);
});

$('#accountTable').dataTable({
   ...
   "aoColumns": aoColumns
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an absolutely **cool** way to do it:

Your header HTML:

```
<table id="sorted-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-s-type="string">Number</th>
            <th data-s-type="html">Complex Name</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th data-b-sortable="false">Action</th>
         </tr>
     </thead>
...
```

Your JS:

```
$('#sorted-table').dataTable({
   ...
   "aoColumns": $('#sorted-table').find('thead tr th').map(function(){return $(this).data()})
});
```

Note: those dashes in data attributes are needed. They get converted to **camelCase** form by jQuery which makes it compatible with the data tables API.

Comment: Yea this is really awesome solution! Nice one!

Answer (score 1):

Having your JS loop through and check for attributes on the headers would work, but you can't just invent an `sType` attribute and have it show up in the DOM. You'd have to subvert a valid but unused attribute like `headers` (and that might cause trouble for screen readers; there may be a better option).

**Edit:**

OK, having read CBroe's comment, I guess it **is** possible to [give an element an arbitrary attribute.](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/customattributes.shtml)

So, if you wanted to be HTML5 compliant, you could name the property `data-sType` and then do something like this:

```
var aoColumns = [];

$('#accountTable > th').each(function() {
   var sType = $(this).getAttribute("data-sType");
   aoColumns.push(sType ? sType : null);
});

$('#accountTable').dataTable({
   ...
   "aoColumns": aoColumns
});
```

Comment: Great! This was nearly perfect. Had to make a couple small tweaks to get it to work for me. See my comment.

Answer (score 1):

Picking up on CBroe's comment, this is exactly what I do.  Just ensure that your custom attributes are prefixed with `data-`, such as `data-stype='currency'` per the [HTML specs](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/customattributes.shtml).