# Specify sType of Datatable based on class

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm using a template, which has the nice feature that all tables with class="datatable" are turned into jQuery datatables:

```
$(".datatable").dataTable();
```

Now, I've been putting different types of data in the tables, and noticed that money and percentage columns are sorted as text, rather than numerically. I added the plugins for sorting as money and percentages ([see here](http://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting)), but they are not getting applied - I suspect because when the tables are initialized, I still have to set the sType of those columns.

I want to do something similar to what was [asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15574745/specify-column-data-type-with-a-th-attribute-for-datatables) - namely, specify in the  tag the sType for the column for the few I need to override. However, since I'm applying the function using a class, not an ID, how do I modify the proposed solution, which scans for the sType attribute, to look based on the specific instance of the class?

```
$(".datatable").each(function() {
    var aoColumns = [];
    $(this).children("th").each(function() {
        var sType = $(this).getAttribute("data-sType");
        aoColumns.push(sType ? { "sType" : sType } : null);
    });
    //$(this).dataTable();
    $(this).dataTable(
            {
                "aoColumns" : aoColumns
            }
        );
});
```

The problem I get with this is that I continually get the error `Cannot read property 'asSorting' of undefined` when I run it with the aoColumns option, but if I run it with no options, it works (minus the sorting functionality).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an attempt at the problem:

http://jsbin.com/ewinep/1
Sort on the "Price" column to see it in action.

http://jsbin.com/ewinep/1/edit
The heart of the matter is in the javascript below that creates the datatables.

```
$(".some-table").each(function(i, v) {
    var aoColumns = []; 
    $(this).find("thead th").each(function() {
      var sType = $(this).data("stype"); // lowercase!
         aoColumns.push(sType ? { "sType" : sType } : null);
    });
   $(this).dataTable({ "aoColumns": aoColumns }); 
});
```

Note that I changed the class name of `.datatable` to `.some-table` for each of the tables (not that it makes any difference - just tired of seeing a css class name and a javascript function of the same name).

As an aside, did you attempt to do a console.log() underneath `$(this).children("th").each(function() {`
to see if *any* code was executing inside the nested `.each`?

Comment: actually, it appears the issue was that I was getting an array of values back from the internal each() statement - once I factored that in, it dealt with the issue.